# Stripe paymentContext does set paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption as default card

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

Yesterday I added stripe sdk for ios, and used its tutorial to implement adding payment option, and everything worked just fine. Today after a bit of refactor of code (did not change anything crucial) `paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption` is nil in delegate method

```
func paymentContextDidChange(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext) {

}
```

When i init `paymentContext` this method is called twice, yesterday first time `paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption` was nil but second time it selected default value, today both times i get nil, any idea why?

This is how i init `paymentContext`:

```
let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: StripeClient.sharedClient)
paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext)
```

Customer is ok, because it can create and read card that are on stripe dashboard, only issue is that default card is not selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason this happened is that at first i was using pod version 15.0.1, and later updated to 16.0.0. I got response from their developer so in short default card is no longer supported.

Here is full response:

> That is intentional and it's a change with the PaymentMethods API
>   there is no such concept as a default PaymentMethod any more. Your
>   integration has to maintain that, and explicitly pass the
>   PaymentMethod you want to charge, there simply is no customer-level
>   default

Answer (score 1):

The feature is managed locally by the Stripe framework since v16.0.2.
You should store the last payment method ID in your user defaults anywhere and then set `STPPaymentContext.defaultPaymentMethod` right after you instantiate the `STPPaymentContext`

https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPPaymentContext.html#/c:objc(cs)STPPaymentContext(py)defaultPaymentMethod

Be sure to follow the note `Set this property immediately after initializing STPPaymentContext, or call retryLoading afterwards.`